# Push viewController inside master UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController`. Inside this `UIViewController` there is a master `UIViewController` and a detail `UIViewController`.

On the master `UIViewController` I have a table view and when a item is selected I want push a new `UIViewController` inside this master view controller without change the detail `UIViewController`.

But, doing this piece of code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewViewController animated:YES];
```

The new `UIViewController` is pushed inside of the`UISplitViewController` and I only want to show the new view controller on the master `UIViewController`.

How can I push a view controller inside this master `UIViewController` without change the detail `UIViewController`?

Comment: you help full this    http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060915/having-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-the-master-view-of-a-uisplitviewcontroller-in